# В каких случаях показывается уведомление о привилегии?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано

Собственно, набрал 15000, [привилегию получил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), а уведомления что-то нет.

У остальных уведомления нормально появляются?
И не связано ли его отсутствие с тем, что во время беты у меня была эта привилегия?

Comment: Они с задержкой показываются. Иногда чере сутки.

Comment: _`с т`_? c чем связано?

Comment: @Grundy, странно, кусок текста исчез. Я его точно писал. Написал ещё раз.

Comment: как недавно получавший данную привилегию, подтверждаю: насколько помню, я тоже не получал уведомление об этом.

Comment: @PashaPash, всё ещё нет уведомления...

Comment: Похоже, дело в Бете. Задал вопрос на Мете, жду ответа разработчика. [Non-veteran users didn't get notified about a new privilege](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274256)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Кстати, поздравляем!

Comment: @VladD, надо хотя бы 20, а лучше 25. А то защита вопросов - что-то не самая полезная возможность.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну это, думаю, не за горами.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен, привилегия не самая интересная. Скоро наберете. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кратко:

- На каждом сайте уведомление о привилегии приходит максимум один раз.
- Потеря привилегии (от потери репутации или от аттестации сайта) не сбрасывает флажок "уже уведомлялся".
- Получившие привилегию на одном сайте сети SE считаются "ветеранами" на других сайтах и получают там уведомления только о части привилегий.

В вашем случае дело в том, что привилегия уже была в Бете.

### Уведомления о привилегиях для разных статусов участника и сайта.

([источник](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151679/296059))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, было бы логичнее сбрасывать?

Comment: @Qwertiy сложная логика, от которой немного пользы. Множеству людей наоборот не понравится, что их многократно уведомляют.

Comment: Я выход из беты имел в виду.

Comment: Эм.. Что-то со справкой баллы не сходятся. 20К - не последняя ступень там.

Comment: да, видимо, так и есть. получил вновь (в бете она у меня уже была) привилегию trusted-user. в профайле информация обновилась, а оповещения так и не было: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DUBLm.png